# How do I assign a large number to a value?

Tags: f#

I am struggling to assign a long number to a value.

```
let cardNumber = 1234567891234567
```

I receive the following error:

> This number is outside the allowable range for 32-bit signed

I then tried:

```
let cardNumber = (int64 1234567891234567)
```

However, I get the same error.

I'm referencing the following [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64(v=vs.110).aspx).
However, I am unaware of what I need to do to make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Being a strongly-typed language, F# requires all literals to have an explicit type.  Numbers without a decimal point which don't have a suffix are considered to be 32 bit integer literals.

In your case, that means 1234567891234567 is a 32 bit integer literal, and as you've noted, 32 bit integers can't be that large.  To tell the compiler that you want it to be a 64-bit integer literal, you need to put an 'L' after it like this:

```
let cardNumber = 1234567891234567L
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals for how to declare different types of literals.